# Scope of the object and manipulation on the object in term of reference type

Tags: c#, .net, oop, object

Please look over the below code. I am not able to rectify that when we create the object of class `Student` named `objStudent1` and we set two values name and roll number now it holds the value

- name: student2
- roll number: 222

And now we pass this object to a function named `ChangeName` as a parameter and here the name of parameter is `objStudent2` and we set again same values, now it holds the value

- name: student3
- roll number: 333

and then we set `objStudent2` object by null value.

After executing the full function `ChangeName` it is printing the value which are set in the `ChangeName` function which are printed from the object `objStudent1`.

Modification done on the data member are reflecting, but null is not reflecting outside from the function on the same object.

```
namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student objStudent1 = new Student();
            objStudent1.Name = "Student2";
            objStudent1.RollNumber = 222;
            ChangeName(objStudent1);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Name-" + objStudent1.Name);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Roll Number-" + objStudent1.RollNumber);
            System.Console.Read();
        }

        private static void ChangeName(Student objStudent2)
        {
            objStudent2.Name = "Student3";
            objStudent2.RollNumber = 333;
            objStudent2 = null;
        }
    }

    class Student
    {
        public string Name = "Student1";
        int _RollNumber = 111;

        public int RollNumber
        {
            get { return _RollNumber; }
            set { _RollNumber = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest me what's going on over here!

I am fully confused!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that objStudent1 and objStudent2 are both references to the same object.  Even after you null out the objStudent2 reference, you still have the objStudent1 reference.  The object is still there.  And then you use the objStudent1 reference to print out the members.

Answer (score 0):

Your reference variables are nothing but mere references to some memory location where your data actually resides.

**For instance:**

```
// this allocates some memory space for your instance/object
 new Student();

//this line also does allocates some memory space but the difference is it has got some reference/agent to access that memory location.
Subject obj = new Student();

//This block has obj and obj1. Both obj and obj1 acts almost like agent/broker to that specific memory location. The line 2 does not mean it is separate object/ memory location but its just another reference to the same memory location.
Subject obj = new Student();
Subject obj1 = obj;

//In 3rd line of this block, you are not nullifying the memory location but you are just trying to nullify the reference alone.It does not make any disturbance to that memory location and its contents.
Subject obj = new Student();
Subject obj1 = obj;
Obj1=null;

// This still will work because this reference to that memory location is not nullified.
Obj.getXXXX();
```

Hope This is Helpful!